# When dialog element gets rendered into DOM?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have the following code snippet (just to illustrate the question, it is not full production code) for the CkEditor plugin:

```
onOk: function() {
    var dialog = this,
    element = dialog.element;
    .........   
    element.setStyle('width', width+'%');
    element.setStyle('text-align', align)
    dialog.commitContent(element); 
}
```

In this small code snippet a modification of one dialog element occurs using `setStyle()` method, after which `commitContent` is triggered.

So, the questions are:

1. Do I understand correctly, that each `setStyle` call here triggers
   element rerender (repaint) since this `element` already exists in
   DOM?
2. What is the purpose of `commitContent()` ckEditor method? Just an event for dialog elements to store some data?

Answer (score 0):

### setStyle

I belive that `setStyle` repaints the components **already existing in the DOM**, have a look at this example (that I have taken from the official [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-setStyle)):

```
var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'myElement' );
element.setStyle( 'background-color', '#ff0000' );
element.setStyle( 'margin-top', '10px' );
element.setStyle( 'float', 'right' );
```

**It first gets the element from the doc** and Then sets the style, so basically it is **repaiting** it triggering events.

### commitContent

From the official [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-method-commitContent):

> Calls the CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.uiElement.commit method of each
>   of the UI elements, with the arguments passed through it. **It is
>   usually being called when the user confirms the dialog, to process the
>   values**.

Hope this helped you!